# What do I edit in V22.03 LTS grub configuration to specify root filesystem?

Tags: boot, grub2, mount

I am modernising from an upgraded Slackware system.
I had that system set up so that it has a small boot drive and a daily-updated mirror drive which was an EXACT copy of the boot drive. Both drives were in hot-swappable mounts so that a failed drive could be replaced in seconds by simply putting the mirror into the boot slot and rebooting.

I'm in the process of setting up the mirror system with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS server.  I have installed, configured and backed up a boot drive and am now in the process of setting up the mirror. I do this by using dd to copy the first  1GiB or so from the boot drive to the mirror drive, use fdisk to delete then redefine the mirror's rootfile system partition, mkfs a clean file system on that partition, then cp -rpd copy all the contents of the boot drive's file system onto the mirror.  Further maintenance of the mirror is done using rsync activated by a cron job and script.

I seem to have created a problem for myself in specifying GPT partitions on both these disks, which caused the install process to configure GRUB so that it uses the 4096(:-D)-digit GPT disk ID to locate the disk containing the filesystem it should mount as root.
To make this work, I need grub on both drives to always go to /dev/sda to find its file system.

I have found a plethora of information online about Debian's version of grub 2 but from what I can see in the /boot directory on my installed systems, Ubuntu's version is substantially different with different configuration requirements.

Can somebody please point me at appropriate documentation and suggest a solution?
Peter

Comment: UUID has been used for about 10 years on the grub "linux" line.  Just edit the root=UUID=xxxxxxx to be root=/dev/sda2 or whatever your root is. Maybe try the /etc/default/grub item GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=false  and run update-grub.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you ubfan1:  Your comment inspired me to an expressly forbidden action.  I edited grub.cfg. First copying it to grub.cfg.original  as a safety measure.
( having those hot-swappable mounts and a spare linux boot disk opens up  options !)
The grub command interpreter specifies gpt partitions using (hdX,gptY) where X is hard disk number (starting at 0) and Y is partition number (starting at 1).
I left all those alone.
Where the interpreter is loading the linux system image 'vmlinuz' a command line is passed to vmlinuz  including root=UUID="GPT_DISK_ID". I replaced all of those with 'root=/dev/sda2'.  I deleted all of the gpt ID's in a few searches as well.

Rebooted and all is well. The mirror drive created with dd also boots perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

That turned out to be an answer that worked for one (count 'em - just one) reboot, after which the crub.cfg was re-written to be exactly the same as before my edits.

It turns out that I should have edited the file /etc/grub.d/10_linux.

I commented out a line:
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_PARTUUID=${GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_PARTUUID-true}

and put in two new lines just below it:
GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_PARTUUID=true

That seems to have worked and I hope the solution is permanent this time.
Peter

Comment: Since posting the above, I have had reason to look at /etc/fstab.   In that file the installation scripts have identified the root filesystem using a GPT UUID.   Changed that to /dev/sda2  as well, just in case - even though it didn't seem to breach a reboot.